# Way to practically identify punycode in Chrome?

Tags: google, chrome, phishing

I recently read some articles about phishing with [punycode](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). To prevent it when using firefox, you simply type `about:config` and turn the parameter `network.IDN_show_punycode = true`. Now you can easily see if somebody tries to scam you. Well, I am using google chrome and I didn't find a practical way to get rid of the risk being deceived. You can look at the certificate, but I am not willing to do that everytime i click on a link... Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Chrome doesn't provide any standard options to enforce Punycode yourself. Instead they apply [their own IDN policy](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/idn-in-google-chrome) to all domains to determine how they should be displayed.

However, there are [several browser extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/punycode) you can use to mitigate the problem. E.g., **[Punycode Alert](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/punycode-alert/djghjigfghekidjibckjmhbhhjeomlda)** warns you if a domain uses Punycode. From the description:

> Punycode Alert is a GPLv3 Google Chrome, Chromium, Opera extension that warns users when the URL they are accessing has some Punycode content to prevent them from being cheated and redirected to a different URL.

(It's also [on Github](https://github.com/i3visio/punycode-alert).)